# Confusion on memory leaks caused by not clearing the timeout in the fetch handlers

Tags: javascript, fetch, settimeout

I am reading blog post on [Promise.race, fetch and avoiding memory leaks](https://kgrz.io/avoiding-memory-leaks-timing-out-fetch.html) and there is one thing I don't quite understand

The naive implementation he mentioned in the blog post causes a memory leak

```
const request = fetch(url, options).then(response => response.json());
const timeout = new Promise((_, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        reject(new Error('Timeout'));
    }, 10000)
});

Promise.race([ request, timeout ]).then(response => {}, error => {})
```

I understand that the callback we pass to `setTimeout` holds references to the promise constructor’s function, but what I don't understand is that it in [the Heap Snapshot](https://kgrz.io/inline-settimeout.605c2274.jpg) he took at the end of the blog post showing that there are a lot of http.agent and related Socket objects got retained because of the inline setTimout version. Why such an implementation would cause the retaintion of http.agent and Socket objects? I thought it was going to retain the promise constructor’s function and that's it.

Comment: I can't really tell what the snapshot means, and it's unclear what exact code was used to produce it. You're right, the http stuff should not be retained by the timeout.

Comment: Since the timeout isn't cleared, the promise isn't cleared, therefor the Promise.race can't be garbage collected, and it points to a promise that points to the request object. He ran many of these so he got many http objects.

Comment: @RaniSharim The promise returned by `Promise.race` does not point to the `request()` promise, and the `request()` promise does not point to the request object - the references are in the other direction, from the `resolve` function to the promise.

Comment: Promise.race([ request, timeout ])... it points to an array with both promises.

Comment: @RaniSharim Those are passed in as arguments, but not stored anywhere to be retained

Comment: @RaniSharim you mean that `reject(new Error('Timeout'));` -> `timeout` -> `[ request, timeout ]` -> `request` so that's why `request` cannot get GCed? I couldn't seem to understand why `reject(new Error('Timeout'));` is going to hold reference to `const timeout`

Comment: @Joji The `reject` function internally holds a reference to the promise object (`timeout`) that it is going to reject. But the `timeout` object does not hold a reference to the array that it is contained in.

Comment: @Bergi yea so it shouldn't cause the memory leak with `request` which is in the array right?

Comment: @Joji Yes, it shouldn't. And if I'm reading the memory snapshot screenshot correctly, they aren't. The sockets are kept (probably for reuse in a pool) at [`globalAgent`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_globalagent)`.sockets`

Comment: @Bergi interesting so the article's claim is false?

Comment: @Joji I guess so? But they definitely are unverifiable, as there's not enough code to reproduce the findings.